Not able to access the value of the select lightning component
Component code
<lightning:card title="New Purchase Order">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            
            <lightning:select aura:id="vendorItemSelect" label="Select Vendor Item" 
                              value="{!v.selectedVendorItem}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.vendorItems}" var="item">
                    <option value="{!item.value}">{!item.label}</option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>


            <!-- Other inputs (e.g., Account Name) -->
            <lightning:input aura:id="Quantity" type="number" step="1" label="Quantity"/>
            
            <!-- Button to save record -->
            <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRecord}"/>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>

controller code

   saveRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
        var vendorItemId = component.find("vendorItemSelect").get("v.value");
        console.log(vendorItemId);
        var quantity = component.find("Quantity").get("v.value");
        

        var action = component.get("c.createPurchaseOrder");

        action.setParams({
            "vendorItemId": vendorItemId,
            "quantity": quantity
        });

        // Set up the callback to handle the response
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var newPurchaseOrderId = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('Purchase Order Created: ' + newPurchaseOrderId);
            } else {
                console.error('Error creating Purchase Order: ' + response.getError());
            }
        });

        // Enqueue the action to send the request to the server
        $A.enqueueAction(action);


    }


When I click the submit button, I expect the saverecord handler to retrieve the selected picklist value in the vendorItemId variable, but its not doing that. I'm not able to access the vendorItemId variable. When I print it in the console, nothing is there. I don't know what is going wrong

Can you add more info when are you making the call in js which you have added in question?

@sanketkumar I've added some info now
